# Python: Creation of array with fill values according to column/row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

[image: 10x10 array]

Suppose you are trying to create a synthetic image 10x10 represented by a matrix of values (numpy array). This image has three blocked sections. In the upper left block, columns 0-4 and rows 0-4, the value will be 1. the right block, columns 5-9 and rows 0-9, will be 0. the remaining area, columns 0-4 and row 5-9, will be 2.(see attached image)

What is the fastest way to create such an object? I understand that you could create an array of zeros and iteratively change the values in each column, but I also understand this is not an efficient method. I assume it involves simply generating the array using np.array, but I'm not quite sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is to create an 'empty' array of `0`, and then fill the blocks of `1` and `2`.  E.g.

```
In [145]: C = np.zeros((10,10), int)

In [146]: C[:4,:4]=1

In [147]: C[:4,5:9]=2

In [148]: C
Out[148]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

You could also make the blocks (with `np.ones` etc), and concatenate them.  `hstack` and `vstack` are just alternative APIs for concatenate.  But concatenate ends up using, in compiled code, this initialize and assign method.  It's a good idea to be familiar with both methods.

Comment: Great. This is the sort of method I was looking for. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

What about,

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((5,5))
b = a*2.
c = np.zeros((10,5))

np.hstack((np.vstack((a,b)),c))
```

Comment: I had thought about doing this, but I wasn't sure if there were any even more compact way to accomplishing this in one go. Perhaps with np.arange?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a homework question? Have a play with `numpy.concatenate` and `numpy.ones` and see how you go.

Comment: No, a visualization for an image segmentation program. I am just very new with python. thank you for your addition.

Answer (score 0):

For simple patterns similar to yours, you can use basic broadcasting:

```
>>> numpy.array([1]*5 + [2]*5)[:,None] * numpy.array([1]*5 + [0]*5)
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

`[:,None]` just adds a second axis, so that instead of a (10,) size array, we have a (10,1) size array which we can then multiply with the (10,) array on the right using broadcasting.

Or, more concisely:

```
>>> numpy.outer([1]*5 + [2]*5, [1]*5 + [0]*5)
```

which gives the same result.